# How do I get rid of odor from cycling shoes?

Tags: shoes, cleaning

So I have a pair of: Diadora X-Country 2 MTB Shoes (pic below)

How would I go about cleaning them, primarily to remove odor? I am tempted to put this in the washing machine- but the cleet is totally stuck to the shoe (imagine 7,000km, mostly in the wet). Brush + washing up liquid? What about the inside sole etc?

Any tips?

[image]

Update:
I ended up using some handwash (with anti bacterial) and a brush/toothbrush and got the following results: 
[image]

Comment: Are you cleaning for cosmetic reasons or reasons related to odour?  I find my shoes get quite stinky if they get wet and don't dry fast enough.  A generous dose of [foot odour spray](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Dr.-Scholl-s-Odor-Destroyers-Spray-4.7-oz/11965062) seems to clear up the problem.

Comment: Bit of both- but odour in this case. Where I store them in work means they don't dry after a soaking :(

Comment: I find that a boot / shoe drier will knock out a lot of the odor.

Comment: I just use a fan to dry mine, it works really well.

Comment: I have seen special racks that go in tumble dryers for shoes to sit on and not tumble.  Might be model specific.

Comment: Clean?  Isn't that what a small stick is for?  (To dry them, stuff with newspaper, replace the newspaper after an hour, and again after 2 more hours, then finally remove the newspaper in the morning.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I have seen suggestions that dishwashers be used to wash things like baseball caps which can not be tumbled/agitated/immersed. I have no idea how well this would work for bike shoes, and of course some folks are going to be squicked by the concept of shoes and dishes being anywhere near each other.

Comment: OT, but if the cleat bolt has rusted into the cleat nut, I would strongly recommend drilling out the old bolts, and replacing them. I've ripped cleats off my shoes because of this. Trust me, you don't want to kneecap yourself on the step while sprinting up a hill. Check the threads on the nut too... if they're corroded, get new nuts. And grease the threads on the new bolts!

Comment: I recommend not smelling them.

Comment: One point needs to be made:  Not all odor is due to bacteria.  Humans (like all animals) produce significant amounts of fatty acids, and these are "expressed" by glands in the underarms, groin area, and, to a lesser extent, the feet.  Fatty acids are hard to wash away and they turn rancid with exposure to air.  It is fatty acids, not bacteria, which are responsible for most of what people call "body odor".

Comment: I'd look at the kind of sprays that bowling alleys use on rental shoes.   Once you get them clean, buy some overshoes for wet days, or ride normal flat shoes/boots with an old cleat in the pedal on wet days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple, yet powerful solution - pour max 1 teaspoon of *sodium bicarbonate* (baking soda, found in any store) into the shoes before or after wearing them. It will kill the bacteria and any other "stuff" that produces bad smell.

**It has no negative effects on skin** whatsoever, ***except when applying it to freshly shaven skin - as it may cause inflammation of the skin*** (but, hey - everything does under that conditions).

It also doesn't paint socks or shirts (if you use it as a deodorant replacement).

I use it on daily basis. Also, it's great if you don't want the irritations on skin from the deodorants.

Sodium Bicarbonate is odorless itself.

[More info on Sodium Bicarbonate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate)

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

If odor is your main concern, I can highly recommend the so-called [boot bananas](http://www.bananafingers.co.uk/boot-bananas-p-1654.html). You put them in your shoes whenever you are not using them, and it slowly kills all odors. I have a pair of boot-bananas for a year now, and I am very enthousiastic about it, all odors are gone since I use them. It did not use them for my cycling shoes though (they don't smell as far as I know), but for other sporting shoes. It is not cheap, but certainly worth the money.

Some people put their shoes in the freezer, as it also kills a lot of the bacteria, which cause the bad smell, but I do not have first hand experience with that.

Comment: Freezing doesn't really help in most cases, in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

I try to not wash cycle shoes.

I have found a boot/shoe dryer to be effective with odor. 
The old style without a fan seems to work better for shoes. 
Leave the dryer in for a day and cook that bacteria. 
No I don't have medical information the dryer gets hot enough to kill bacteria but it seems to work. 
It gets rid of the odor and the next time they get wet they don't seem to stink up as fast. 
And a fresh set of socks with every ride.

According to this link you can kill odor bacteria with heat 
[Foot odor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_odor)

> Remove odor causing bacteria with Ozone, Sunlight, UV, Chemical, or
>   Heat.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Soaking them in a bucket of very diluted bleach water (~1 cap in a 5 gallon bucket) overnight should help with the odor.

As far as drying, either grab a fan, or there are a lot of commercial solutions available.  They're mostly marketed for winter/ski boots, but they'll obviously work for any type of wet shoe.

Comment: Generally, chlorine bleach is not very effective for this sort of thing.  Hydrogen peroxide is more effective, but I'm not sure I'd recommend either for relatively expensive shoes.

Answer (score 3):

Start by replacing the insoles.  Typically this is what smells the most in old bike shoes.

After that you can also clean the shoe itself following any one of the many suggested methods outlined in this thread.  But be sure to remove you nice new insoles first before cleaning the shoe itself.  Also try to thoroughly dry the shoe as fast as possible, leaving the shoe damp for prolonged period will encourage growth of bacteria.

Good luck!

Comment: Insoles definitely need attention. Remove them to properly dry the shoes (often they are foam, so no air movement to dry anything below them). Definitely replace if needed, but removing and cleaning the insoles will make them last longer (and keep the shoe from stinking).

Answer (score 1):

Dettol Liquid contains Chloroxylenol. It kills bacteria and provides protection against germs which can cause infection and illness. Dettol kills 99.9% of bacteria, such as E.coli and Influenza virus (H1N1). Always read the label.

Serious, the smell is caused by bacteria and your mission is to kill them!

1. Put hot water, plenty of Dettol and your bacteria/shoes in a bucket.
2. Let it soak for one night.
3. Rinse and dry.

Enjoy the new smell!

Comment: That will probably only kill 99.9% of the bacteria ;-)

Comment: I don't think influenza is really something you have to worry about in cycling shoes. And viruses aren't bacteria.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not know this but baking soda can act as a good deodorizer for the shoes and sometimes even for the feet.
 - After using your shoes, sprinkle a little bit of baking soda on each
   one.
 - Leave on the baking soda on the shoes overnight.
 - Take off the baking soda from the shoes in the morning especially if
   it is already going to be used.
[More info](http://naturalremedyideas.com/get-rid-of-shoe-odor/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unconventional, but stay with me.

1. Take the shoes and place them in a plastic bag.
2. Remove as much air as you can from the bag and seal.
3. Place the bagged shoes in to the freezer.
4. Leave the shoes in the freezer at least overnight.

I based this on the idea that the cold temps of the freezer would kill most of the odor causing bacteria and it worked the times I've tried it, but your milage may very.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a boot dryer. Put your wet shoes and gloves on it after good rides. It drys them out fast and prevents odors.  Great for winter commuting as well.

When my MTB shoes are covered in mud. I just take them to the sink with a scrub brush. Do a quick rinse and scrub the outside (about 2 min tops) to get the mud off and then toss on the dryer.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link/model/make please? Thanks!

Comment: I use the dry guy boot dryer here, works great. http://www.amazon.com/DryGuy-Wide-Body-Boot-Glove-Dryer/dp/B0000AMK8R