# What is this apparatus for?

Tags: shoes

I saw [this post by Ji Cheng](https://twitter.com/jicheng369/status/485026087039422464/photo/1) (Lanterne Rouge) on Twitter. My question is about the apparatus he posts a picture of. It contains (his?) shoes. Simple question, what is this machine exactly doing? Is it to [get rid of odors](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23334/how-do-i-get-rid-of-odor-from-cycling-shoes/)?

[image: Apparatus cycling shoes]

Comment: Best guess is that it is a (greatly overpriced) shoe dryer.

Comment: @DanielRHicks That sounds plausible, but I could not find it.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find it either.  But Google images for "drying box" and you will see a number of roughly similar devices.

Comment: Concievably a shoe dryer does get rid of some odors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a machine used for heating the shoes so that they can be formed to your feet. the shoes are heated. You then put them on your feet and they use a vacuum bag around the shoe to compress it against your foot so it gets the proper shape. [Here's an article](http://www.wired.com/2012/05/shimano-2012-r315/) that explains it. I've had something similar done for hockey skates, although without the vacuum, and the result was quite comfortable skates. Hockey skates are quite hard, so I could see this being necessary to get the right shape. Cycling shoes are often rigid, at least in the sole, so I could see it helping with fit.

Comment: This same concept has been used in ski boots for years. The shoe's upper contains some product that, when heated, softens, and when cooled retains the molded shape. I have a pair of MTB shoes for which this was done and they are extremely comfortable after molding.

Comment: They should figure out a way to do something similar for saddles.

Comment: Hah!  I don't think you want to sit your taint on a heated saddle and then have a vacuum bag placed around that whole *AREA* and clamped down.  Or, if you do, there are probably other places on the internet that are more interesting than the bicycle area of stackexchange ;)

Comment: @ChrisCleeland your weight would probably be enough to make a proper mold, you wouldn't need a vacuum bag. And it doesn't really get that hot. Otherwise the process would burn your foot.

Comment: my foot is a bit less sensitive than my taint, but I understand your point.